# Installing MAAS 2.7 always stuck at “Initializing Database”

Tags: server, maas

First post here. I am installing MAAS 2.7 following the documentation - https://maas.io/docs/install-from-a-snap However, every time I attempt to init MAAS with `sudo maas init --mode all` it never moves past `“Initializing Database”`

I am installing MAAS in a virtual lab environment running VMware Workstaion 15.5 Pro

VM details are as follows:

- OS = Ubuntu 18.04 Server
- vCPUS = 2
- RAM = 2GB
- Disk = 50GB
- 2 NICs

  - 1 for mgmt network
  - 1 for node deployment network

I cannot find anything online to point me in the right direction to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: This person seemed to get around it by installing via apt
https://discourse.maas.io/t/installing-maas-2-7-always-stuck-at-initializing-database/1455